# Cannot hide title top bar on Nexus 7

Tags: android, styles, titlebar

My app shows top title bar on Nexus 7 and I can't achieve to hide it. My files :

*styles.xml*

```
<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="MyAppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="MyAppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go here. -->
</style>
```

*values-v11/styles.xml*

```
<!--
    Base application theme for API 11+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from res/values/styles.xml on API 11+ devices.
-->
<style name="MyAppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- API 11 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

*values-v14/styles.xml*

```
<!--
    Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
    AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
    res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
-->
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- API 14 theme customizations can go here. -->
</style>
```

and I also added this to my main Activity :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add

```
  getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, 
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

To your main activity.